# Finding an exact match of the text in list

Tags: python

I want to check if there is an exact match of the text in a list.

```py
lst = ["Hi my name is ", "apple "]
new_lst = [t.strip() for t in lst]
text = input("text: ").lower()
if text in new_lst:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

But when I input `hi my name is`

I get `false` instead of `true`.
How can I fix this?

Comment: String equality checks are case sensitive. In your list, `'Hi'` starts with a capital `'H'`.

Comment: thanks I haven't realized my mistake

Comment: @timgeb not sure that would work without removing the `.lower()` in `input("text: ").lower()`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε That what would work? I stated a fact, I did not propose a solution.

Comment: @timgeb right, my bad :) I understood it like _"you should use a capital `H` in the input"_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alluded to by @timgeb, in Python string equality checks are case sensitive.

It is fairly commonplace to normalize both the inputs and the data to ensure that case sensitivity is not a problem. In your code, since you are processing each element of the `lst` to remove extra spaces, it is pretty straightforward to also normalize the text in your `lst` to be lowercase as well.

```
lst = ["Hi my name is ", "apple "]
new_lst = [t.strip().lower() for t in lst]  # using method chaining
                                            # to lowercase the stripped text
                                            # by applying .lower()

text = input("text: ").lower()
if text in new_lst:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new_lst = [t.strip().lower() for t in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
lst = ["Hi my name is ", "apple "]
new_lst = [t.strip().lower() for t in lst]
text = input("text: ").lower()
print("True" if text.lower() in new_lst else "False")
```

This code will change all the characters in the lst list to lower and will compare the input text as lower case and by that, you will get a match.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip and lowercase directly while comparing like this:

```
lst = ["Hi my name is ", "apple "]
text = input("text: ").lower()
if text in [e.strip().lower() for e in lst]:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```